# C++\CLI how to create utils class with methods accessible to many other classes

Tags: templates, generics, c++-cli

I have a number of classes that use identical generic functions/methods. At present I have coded these methods for each class, but this involves unnecessary duplication. So I want to move these methods to a Utils class that can be accessed by all classes that need to make use of these methods. I think this can be done with `Generic` or with `Template`, but I don't have an example that I can understand.

This is what I do now (left out all non-essentials):

Genome.h:

```
ref class Genome
{
public:
    List<wchar_t>^ stringToList(String^ inString);  // convert string to List with  chars
};
```

Genome.cpp:

```
List<wchar_t>^ Genome::stringToList (String^ inString)
{
    List<wchar_t>^ tmpList = gcnew List<wchar_t>(); 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < inString->Length; i++)
        tmpList->Add(inString[i]);
    return tmpList;
}
```

and a typical method call would look like this:

```
cString->AddRange(stringToList(aLine)); // genome string is stored as one line
```

where cString is of type `List<wchar_t>^`

So if I were to move the `stringToList` method to a `Utils.h` and `Utils.cpp` class, what would the code look like, and how do I the call this and other Utils methods in classes Genome.cpp and others?

Thanks, Jan

Comment: Take a look to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8991/Using-generics-in-C-CLI) about generics. At the beginning of it, there is a link to another one explaning diferences between generics and templates. About make _Utils::StringToList()_ method accesible everywhere, just mark it as static.

Comment: @Jairo: static works indeed! That basically solves my current issue. I did come across that article, but I will give it some more study. Thanks, Jan

Answer (score 0):

I put my utility functions in a class that I mark as abstract sealed. Since the class is abstract sealed, you cannot create instances of it, therefore all members have to be declared as static. The result is equivalent of having free functions.

E.g. in the header you will have

```
public ref class MyUtils abstract sealed
{

    // ........................................................................

    private:

        static MyUtils ();

    public:

        static System::Double CalculateAverage  ( cli::array<System::Double>^ arrayIn );



};
```

and in the .cpp

```
MyUtils::MyUtils ()
{
}


System::Double MyUtils::CalculateAverage ( cli::array<System::Double>^ arrayIn )
{
    // the code doing the calculation...
}
```

You call this method as you call any static method

e.g.

```
cli::array<System::Double>^ values = gcnew cli::array<System::Double>(5);
    // ...
    // put some data in the array
    // ...
System::Double average = MyUtils::CalculateAverage ( values );
```

Of course you can have generic methods as member of this class too.